# I changed ec2 instance type from t2.medium to c5.xlarge and i can't useit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I changed a ec2 instance type from t2.medium to c5.xlarge
When restarted success. I can't connect it in private network.

ssh got error:Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host ip-xx.internal port 22: Connection refused

before that, all is well

ena driver is enabled. but ethtool -i eth0 got vif

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/amazon/ena/ena.ko
version:        1.0.2
license:        GPL
description:    Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
author:         Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates
srcversion:     73A3C8A8AA3F11D64B6D173
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd0000EC21sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd0000EC20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd00001EC2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd00000EC2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.0-7-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
```

```
shell #sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: vif
version:
firmware-version:
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: vif-0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: one option: the internal ip address has changed.

Comment: If you reset it back to a `t2.medium`, can you connect? You'll probably find that whatever the cause, it is unrelated to the instance type. Check that you are connecting to the correct Public IP address (the public IP can change when an instance is stopped/started, but the internal IP address stays the same).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if back to t2.medium and all is well.no public address, private server.

Comment: @LiorBar-On no,use private dns, not changed.

Comment: Which AMI are you using that causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emmmmm

OS: debian stretch

install nvme driver
`sudo apt install nvme-cli`

change`/etc/fstab`use`blkid`do not use `/dev/xx`

poweroff, change instance type and boot. success.